# make a record by slug

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has a slug, but when trying to register it does not allow it, generating the following error not null constraint failed: commentaries_commentarie.post_id.

this is model:

```
class Commentarie(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentarie = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

this is urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.CommentarieCreateView.as_view(), name='add_commentarie'),
]
```

this is view:

```
class CommentarieCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'commentaries/commentarie.html'
    model = Commentarie
    form_class = CommentarieForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return redirect('posts:post')
```

also try to create the relation, getting directly by the kwarg but it generates an error, because it turns out that it is waiting for a pk object, and it slug it is generated correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your `post` property in `Commentarie` cannot be `null` in the database. You need to either provide a value or allow it to be `null`.

To set the post object you can do something like this...

```py
class CommentarieCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'commentaries/commentarie.html'
    model = Commentarie
    form_class = CommentarieForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.post = # A Post object
        self.object.save()
        return redirect('posts:post')
```

To allow it to be null change it to...

```py
class Commentarie(models.Model):
    ...
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Once you change it you will need to run your database migration again.

Comment: but what I need is that it is not null, because it will be related to a post.

Comment: Then you have to supply a `post`. You are seeing this error because `post` is `None`.

Comment: But how does it know which `Post`? Your form or view needs to specify the `Commentarie.post` as a `Post` object instance before you can successfully save the new `Commentarie` instance. See my updated answer.

Comment: I get it by slug and instantiate the model to be able to register

Comment: Getting the post is only half of it. You have to set the value of `Commentarie.post` to that post object e.g. `commentarie.post=the_post`.

Comment: look now you can get it and register it in the model, this was the way.
posts = Post.objects.get (slug = self.kwargs ['slug'])
self.object.post = posts

Thanks a lot :)